# How do I plot a function of 3 variables in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot $F = x^2+y^2+z^2$ (an ellipsoid) using the Matlab `surf()` function, but with no luck. I understand the error (`F` is 3d) but I'm not sure which function to use to plot F?

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10,1:20,1:20);
F = sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2+Y.^2);
surf(X,Y,F)
```

*Error using matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Surface
Value must be a vector or 2D array of numeric type.*

Is there a different plotting function to use for display surfaces like this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [fimplicit3](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fimplicit3.html) is the answer!